# If and elif loop is not calculating the sum correctly which is inputed as a float

Tags: python

```
    def statement(transactions):
        new_transactions = [float(i) for i in transactions]
        deposits = []
        withdrawals = []
        mySum = 0
        for num in new_transactions:
            if num >= 0:
                mySum = mySum + num
                mySum = deposits
                return mySum
            elif num < 0:
                mySum = mySum + num
                mySum = withdrawals
                return withdrawals
```

the input into python by a user would be something like this:

```
    >>>account([33.98, -11.22, 23.23, -33.00])
    [57.21, -44.22]
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your for loop only runs for one iteration, because both sides of the if statement return from the function.

Comment: I don't think your code is complete here... you can't go from your user input to your function without "plumbing"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statements should be *after* the loop. Currently the code runs through the loop once, hits one of the return statements, then exits. Additionally, the `mySum = deposits` and `mySum = withdrawals` lines aren't doing what you're looking for, they're setting `mySum` to `[]`. If you want `deposits` and `withdrawals` to be lists of transactions, your code would look like:

```
def statement(transactions):
    new_transactions = [float(i) for i in transactions]
    deposits = []
    withdrawals = []
    mySum = 0
    for num in new_transactions:
        mySum += num
        if num >= 0:
            deposits.append(num)
        else:
            withdrawals.append(num)
    return mySum, deposits, withdrawals
```

Now if a user enters `statement([7, -5, 2, 3])` the function will return a tuple `(12.0, [7.0, 2.0, 3.0], [-5.0])`

### EDIT

You may want to change `withdrawals.append(num)` to `withdrawals.append(-num)` if you wish to get the withdrawals as a list of positive numbers instead of negative ones.

Additionally, consider replacing `[float(i) for i in transactions]` with `(float(i) for i in transactions)`. The difference is that the first is a *list comprehension*, a shorthand for building up a list, while the second is a *generator expression*. Generators don't build up a list, and you pretty much only use them with `for`. The generator will start empty and when `for num in new_transactions` is called, the generator will make *only the first item* and set `num` to it. Then when the next item is needed on the second iteration of the loop, the generator will make the second item. Generators make items one at a time as you need them, whereas with a list you have to make every single item and store them all in memory before entering the `for` loop. This would be a big difference in memory usage if your `transactions` list is, say, a million items.

Comment: mySum += num
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: I'd also be tempted to change the list-comp `new_transactions = [float(i) for i in transactions]` to a generator expression instead as the list isn't needed after: eg: `new_transactions = (float(i) for i in transactions)`

Comment: @Jason I suspect you're doing: `statement(1.23)` or similar - you need to pass in an iterable, eg: `statement([1.23])`

Comment: no i am doing statement([55.95, -18.67, 55.56, -56.00, 40.78])

Comment: @Jason if you copy/paste this code exactly, you get `(77.62, [55.95, 55.56, 40.78], [-18.67, -56.0])`... check you copied it correctly...

Comment: @Jason - I'm not getting that error, do you have more information?
Jon Clements - Good point. I'll add an edit with a note about generator expressions.

Comment: Thank you guys. i had an extra line in there in my old code. I also added (sum(deposits) and same for withdrawals since i needed the sum. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Colonel is right....My sum and withdrawals can not be used in second iteration because they are returned and not inside memory any more....Problem with the loop is that,according to my knoweledge for loop can only use integers to iterate,but maybe you can make it work with while making exit condition (like while i